# Rendering Javascript animated image background over all layouts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background like [particleground](https://jnicol.github.io/particleground/) that I have in mind to build. I want to just lay particleground over a default image I get from the web, and then put it as my constant background for all the webpages I create in Rails. So basically, kind of like a background partial, with other HTML overlaid on top of it, instead of beneath or above. Structure of the project is relatively simple.

I'm assuming this is a pretty basic question, so I apologize if that's the case, but I'm struggling to find any questions that ask this (only getting information about threading).

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you're asking. Would you be more specific?

Comment: I'm wondering how I can put an image behind every page in my web app, in the HTML presumably, such that all the elements for each individual page are superimposed on it.

Comment: @PianoFingers You should tag your question with `html` and `css` then, this has nothing to do with the `rails` framework

Comment: @PianoFingers perhaps you can post some code so we can see your attempt at this